# Is there a module for automatic menu translation?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I need to automatically translate menu items into all enabled languages when created.
Is there a module for that or how can I do it programmatically ?

Comment: What are you planning to use to automatically translate text from one language to another?

Comment: I want to create the menu item, my goal is that the items will be available in all languages (the text in source language)

Comment: You mean: How to automatically clone menu items to all available languages? Or something like that? So when you add one item in one language you want it added for all other languages automatically?

Comment: Yes! that's what i meant :)

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds like not such a good idea – even if there was such a module (which i doubt) and the automatic translation was accureate (which i aloso doubt). IMHO you will probably have lots of annoyed users that don't find content in their language even when 'clicking the right link' **and** be penalized by search engines for duplicate content. Or maybe I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: no

**Long answer**: I wouldn't recommend to try to 'automatically translate' any of your content – especially not translating the navigation while keeping the content in the original language. You will probably rather quickly have lots of frustrated users (or no users at all) that don't find content in *their* language, even when they are '*clicking the right link*'.

Additionally you will probably be penalized by search engines for duplicate content.

Maybe you should ask over at the [ux forum](http://ux.stackexchange.com) what people think of the idea? I suppose hardly anybody would recommend to have that type of mis-leading navigation structure on a website.

There are however various modules to tranlate menues (and fields and taxonomies etc.) on the fly, while you are creating new content items – but that you probably already know – and that's probably not what you were looking for.

Comment: I tried to edit your question 'cause I wanted to take back the (-1) –– only possible after question is edited…

Comment: I have just edited now :)